# How can I compile my C++ code with Mesos?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I got a cluster of 1 master node and 2 slaves and I'm trying to compile my application with mesos.

Basically, here is the command that I use:

```
mesos-execute --name=alc1 --command="ccmake -j myapp" --master=10.11.12.13:5050
```

Offers are made from the slave but this compilation task keeps failing.

```
[root@master-node ~]# mesos-execute --name=alc1 --command="ccmake -j myapp" --master=10.11.12.13:5050
I0511 22:26:11.623016 11560 sched.cpp:222] Version: 0.28.0
I0511 22:26:11.625602 11564 sched.cpp:326] New master detected at master@10.11.12.13:5050
I0511 22:26:11.625952 11564 sched.cpp:336] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0511 22:26:11.627279 11564 sched.cpp:703] Framework registered with 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0139
Framework registered with 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0139
task alc1 submitted to slave 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-S2
Received status update TASK_RUNNING for task alc1
Received status update TASK_FAILED for task alc1
I0511 22:26:11.759610 11567 sched.cpp:1903] Asked to stop the driver
I0511 22:26:11.759639 11567 sched.cpp:1143] Stopping framework '70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0139'
```

On the sandbox slave node, here is the stderr logs:

```
I0511 22:26:13.781070  5037 exec.cpp:143] Version: 0.28.0
I0511 22:26:13.785001  5040 exec.cpp:217] Executor registered on slave 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-S2
sh: ccmake: command not found
I0511 22:26:13.892653  5042 exec.cpp:390] Executor asked to shutdown
```

Just to mentionned that commands like this work fine and get me the expected results:

```
[root@master-node ~]# mesos-execute --name=alc1 --command="find / -name a" --master=10.11.12.13:5050
I0511 22:26:03.733172 11550 sched.cpp:222] Version: 0.28.0
I0511 22:26:03.736112 11554 sched.cpp:326] New master detected at master@10.11.12.13:5050
I0511 22:26:03.736383 11554 sched.cpp:336] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0511 22:26:03.737730 11554 sched.cpp:703] Framework registered with 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0138
Framework registered with 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0138
task alc1 submitted to slave 70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-S2
Received status update TASK_RUNNING for task alc1
Received status update TASK_FINISHED for task alc1
I0511 22:26:04.184813 11553 sched.cpp:1903] Asked to stop the driver
I0511 22:26:04.184844 11553 sched.cpp:1143] Stopping framework '70582e35-5d6e-4915-a919-cae61c904fd9-0138'
```

I don't really get what is needed for even troubleshot this issue.

Comment: Is `ccmake` installed on the slaves? I don't think that it'll work this way, my suggested solution would be to create a Docker image with the necessary tools and to map the source folder as a Docker volume during runtime.